# Add Double elements to 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I have a 2d array named multi and its declaration is

```
Object[][] multi = new Object[10][10];
```

I tried to add some elements like that x and y are Integers

```
 multi[y][x]=10;
```

not when i print anything from this `array` or the hole `array` i got `null`output the whay i print

```
System.out.println(multi[0][0]);
```

or

```
for(int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {
   for(int g = 0; g <10; g++) {
       System.out.println(multi[r][g]);
   }
}
```

Comment: you should get 99 `null` prints, and one print with `10`, if you only assign one value. Could you include the whole code, or rather the method that is executed this specific code.

Comment: All of the elements of `multi[r]` (for `0 <= r < 10`) are initially `null`; they would only not be if you assign them a non-null value subsequently.

Comment: no m8 also when i add oly one element 
 `multi[0][0]=10;`
and print oly one element like that
`System.out.println(multi[0][0]);`

 i got a `null` print

Comment: If you set multi[0][0]=10; and then print it, you WILL get "10",

Comment: @ring bearer no i got a null output

Comment: @special - Then definitely you have something going on with your code. You will get better input if you paste actual relevant piece of your code.

Answer (score 1):

Put values to array and print them.

```
Object[][] multi = new Object[10][10];
Double d        = 0.1;
Double anotherD = 2.5;

multi[0][0] = d       ;
multi[1][3] = anotherD;

for (int i = 0; i < multi.length; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < multi[i].length; j++) 
    {
        System.out.println(multi[i][j]);
    }
}
```

You should see following output when run the above code:

0.1
null
[lots of nulls ommited]
null
2.5
null
[lots of nulls ommited]
null

Answer (score 0):

If you array stores obects of the type `Object` you should consider adding real objects and not just an undeclared value.

`Object[][] multi = new Object[10][10];`

Instead of:
`multi[0][0] = 10;`
You should use
`multi[0][0] = new Double(10);`

Or you do an additional step and declare a variable for that

`Double dValue = 10;
multi[0][0] = dValue;`

If you only store one type of object (or basic type) you should consider declaring an array of that specific type; e.g. for double:

`double[][] multi = new double[10][10];`